# Method render does not exist Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

Method render does not exist error also in links() method
this is my blade 
[blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okplh.png)

this is my controller 
[controller.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGHRL.png)

Comment: **Please don't provide code as images**

Answer (score 0):

`render()` [isn't used for pagination anymore](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results).

In Laravel 5.4 you use `links()` to display the links:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($news as $newsItem)
        {{ $newsItem->whatever }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $news->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Displaying Pagination Results**

When calling the paginate method, you will receive an instance of  `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`. When calling the simplePaginate method, you will receive an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`. These objects provide several methods that describe the result set. In addition to these helpers methods, the paginator instances are iterators and may be looped as an array. So, once you have retrieved the results, you may display the results and render the page links using Blade:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($news as $newsItem)
        {{ $newsItem->whatever }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $news->links() }}
```

See more about Laravel 5.4 pagination [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination)